# po object results in error: cannot find interface declaration for '$__lldb_objc_class'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, lldb, llvm-clang

I'm having this weird functionality in the debug console.

say you have the following code:

```
anIssue.issueID=[issueDictionary objectForKey:@"uniqueId"];
```

the po of the issueDictionary function correctly:

> {
>       Title = "december 2012";
>       coverUrl = "htt://toeete.com/CoverURL/77111a51-32d8-4c39-912e-a889bad250e6.png";
>       downloadUrl = "htt://oetoeto.com/pdfFile/TR December 2012 Single.pdf";
>       "end_date" = "12/31/2013";
>       images =     (
>       );
>       "release_date" = "02/26/2013";
>       summary = "december 2012 issue";
>       uniqueId = "december 2012_1";
>       updated = "02/11/2013"; }

But whenever i try to print-object of "anIssue.issueID" or "[issueDictionary objectForKey:@"uniqueId"]" it fails with:
error: cannot find interface declaration for '$__lldb_objc_class'

say like :

> po [anIssue issueID]

or

> po [issueDictionary objectForKey:@"uniqueId"]

both fails with the error... Though if i

> po anIssue

It succeeds!!!!!!!!

> : ID=december 2012_1 Title=december 2012
>   Released=2013-02-25 22:00:00 +0000 Free=YES Description=december 2012
>   issue

Any idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as trojanfoe indicated, it seems that it's a bug...
refer to : [devforums.apple.com/message/758329#758329](http://devforums.apple.com/message/758329#758329)

And please consider to upvote his comment under my question. 
Thank you

Comment: Has someone filed a radar about this?  I would do it but I always get an error when trying to log into the bug reporting site (ironic...bug reporting site has a bug)

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.6.1 was released a couple of days ago and a couple of problems that would lead to people getting `cannot find interface declaration for '$__lldb_objc_class'` have been resolved.   Please try updating to Xcode 4.6.1 if you're seeing this problem.